# sitting on a bar stool, her legs perpendicular

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Something about the place makes time feel expansive and I become
>   acutely aware of the smallest details. I notice a woman sitting on a
>   bar stool, **her legs perpendicular**, resting on a nearby banister so
>   that they form a little drawbridge, which she raises and lowers as
>   people pass by.

(The Geography of Bliss  by Eric Weiner)

Am I right to understand she sits on a bar stool with her legs like the ones in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cute picture, but, no. It's the "drawbridge" that could have given you the right idea: Assume the woman is sitting upright, then her legs, if perpendicular with her body, are parallel to the ground.

Picture her with her heels on a second stool (instead of the banister) and it might be easier.

Until I find a better picture, turn yours 90 degrees clockwise and you should be close enough. (If necessary, add an imagined bar stool under her rear and the banister under her feet.)

Comment: I couldn't find a better picture but what I imagined was what you just told me - turning the picture 90 degree clockwise.  Thank you for confirming it.